# Using local variable with scanf in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, scanf

I am supposed to recreate a section of code from C in Assembly and I am a little confused about pushing local variables onto the stack frame. I am supposed to call scanf and store the result in a local variable "x". So far this is what I have:

This is to allocate 20 bytes for local variable "x":

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 20
```

I am then to call scanf:

```
push offset formats
;???
call scanf
```

Where `formats` is in the `.data` section:

```
formats db "%s", 0
```

Usually, I have a buffer in the `.data` section that I push the offset of onto the stack, though that would negate the local variable in this case. I am confused about what I am to push onto the stack in order to get `scanf` to store the string in the local variable. Would something like this work?

```
mov [ebp - 20], 0
```

Here is the C code (ignore the for loop):

```
int main(){
    char x[20];
    scanf("%s", x);
    for(char* curr = x; *curr != 0; curr++){
        printf("%c/n", *curr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Referencing the local variable, moving it to a register, then pushing the register worked for me. If this is wrong, please comment but I believe this is right

```
mov ebp, [esp - 20]
push ebp
```

Comment: This is to reload the scanf result?  Yes, but don't use EBP as the temporary register!  Use EAX or something call-clobbered.  Or just `push dword [esp - 20]`.  (Or MASM syntax, `push dword ptr [esp - 20]`).  Push works with a memory source operand.